# Postgres Query to group data by day/week/month from timestamp

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, google-analytics, sequelize.js

My goal is to get the statistics count of data through timestamp, some what like google analytics. I'm using node.js & sequelize The timestamp field in model looks

```
request_timestamp: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
```

For now, I want to get data grouped by day of every timestamp. I tries date_truc but it's not working for some reason.

Comment: "not working for some reason" does not help us figure out what's wrong. Is there an error message? See this page for how to improve your question and get the answer you want https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, I believe your problem has something to do with the fact that you've made your `request_timestamp` of type `STRING` instead of `DATE`. `date_truc` only works on postgres timestamps.